# Entity Framework "Invalid object name 'Item_id'"

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a solution that has spontaneously started generating the error "Invalid object name 'Item_id'". I have searched for this but all answers seem related to code first issues around pluralization; my project is database first.

The context is that there is a Purchase with a collection of ItemPurchaseLines which are linked to Items. The error occurs when a new purchase is generated, this generates new ItemPurchaseLines and either links them to existing Items or generates new Items. The mapping between ItemPurchaseLines and Items is via a foreign key on Item_Id to Id respectively.

I have regenerated the model from the database and the relationships/column mappings all look good.

Any help, or any further information you need, would be appreciated.

**Edit**
I have built a LinqToSql alternative and it gives exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I am a complete idiot!

I completely forgot that I added a trigger to the relevant table to update the pl_Items table but instead of using the correct table name I used Item_Id.

So the code from VS was all good it was the SQL Trigger in the back and that was screwing things up!